# ¿Existe algún estándar para hacer una instancia del DBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp, entity-framework-6

Hace algún tiempo venía utilizando a `DBContext` de la siguiente manera:

```
using(DBContext Database = new DBContext() {
    return(Database.Users.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList());
}
```

El asunto es que di con una página donde recomiendan utilizar a `DBContext` como una propiedad `protected` de una clase abstracta, sería algo así:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        Database = new DatabaseContext();
    }

    protected DatabaseContext Database { get; set; }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Database.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Y luego simplemente se usaría heredando a los Controllers de `BaseController` y utilizando a `Database` normalmente:

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Database.Users.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList());
    }
}
```

¿Existe algún método recomendado por la documentación oficial?

O si existe algún otro recomendado como mejor práctica.

Comment: Con el de la clase abstratcta (nunca lo he usado) pero veo que el contexto está siempre abierto mientras que el controler este ejecutando, puede q pierdas un poco el control de contexto de esta forma... Por otro lado si no necesitas acceder a la base de datos, ejem, recuperar un archivo específico, has abierto un contexto innecesariamente por lo que deberías planear bien los controlers para no abrir contextos innecesarios. mientras aceptes esas cuestiones en los contextos... no la veo mal....
Mejores prácticas, hay miles, según contextos y necesidades